# How to wrap all elements inside a div after a certain element? (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an article tag that has elements inside it.

**Problem:** How can I wrap all elements inside a div after a certain element?

**This is the current code:**

```
<article>
     <figure class="thumbnail">
          <img src="src_to_img" />
     </figure>

      <h2>Name: Test Name</h2>
      <div class="description"></div>
      <div class="content"></div> 
      <div class="content"></div>
      <div class="more"></div>
<article>
```

The **output** must be:

```
<article>
     <figure class="thumbnail">
          <img src="src_to_img" />
     </figure>

      <div class="description-wrap"> 
         <h2>Name: Test Name</h2>
         <div class="description"></div>
         <div class="content"></div> 
         <div class="content"></div>
         <div class="more"></div>
      </div>   
<article>
```

As you can see.. the final output has all the elements wrapped inside `class="description-wrap"` after `<figure></figure>`

Comment: `$("figure ~ *").wrapAll("<div class='description-wrap'></div>")` If there are multiple, then select each `article` and operate on each one.

Comment: agreed with @squint, nice solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @squint suggested, jQuery has a [wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) method that can do that if combined with the [next-siblings-selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) `~`

```
$("article > figure ~ *").wrapAll("<div class='description-wrap'></div>")
```

however, this doesn't give you the desired output when you have multiple articles. Instead we need to use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) like so:

```js
$("article > figure").each(function(){
  $(this).siblings().wrapAll("<div class='description-wrap'></div>")
});
```

```css
.description-wrap {border:1px dotted red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
     <figure class="thumbnail">
          <img src="src_to_img" />
     </figure>

      <h2>Name: Test Name</h2>
      <div class="description"></div>
      <div class="content"></div> 
      <div class="content"></div>
      <div class="more"></div>
</article>
  
  <article>
     <figure class="thumbnail">
          <img src="src_to_img" />
     </figure>

      <h2>Name: Test Name</h2>
      <div class="description"></div>
      <div class="content"></div> 
      <div class="content"></div>
      <div class="more"></div>
</article>
```

Comment: Hi Moob.. Thanks for the answer... I have 4 article tags.. when i run your code.. it messes the whole css.. do you know of another tweak to this?